# EAN transaction data set

Tags: data-request, shopping

I'm looking for a real set of shop transactions data contain EAN code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number)  as transaction item. Community, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
https://barcodesdatabase.org/selected-products/
Barcodelookup also has an API but I`ve never used it before - https://www.barcodelookup.com/api
Hope this helps!